# Order by ascending an alpha-numeric field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I need to order by ascending an alpha-numeric field (SQL Server).The name of the field is OPE_libelle, you can see an extract from the database.

[image: here]

To do that I had created a function to keep the number only(FN_RESTRICT) but I would like to keep the number only when it's a simple OP ( OP 10 become 10, OP 4500 becomes 4500 ...) and for "OP 10 et OP 20" or "OP 10 7107" I keep like that. I need to do that in my SQL request but don't modify the field in my database.

I tried this but the condition is not respected :

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN LEN(OPE_libelle)<= 8 THEN
CAST(dbo.FN_RESTRICT(OPE_libelle, '0123456789') AS INTEGER)
ELSE 
OPE_libelle
END
FROM TR_OPERATION ORDER BY OPE_libelle
```

Error message: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'OP 10 7107' to data type int.

Or the length of 'OP 10 7107' is > 8 so I don't ask to convert it (it should have passed in the "else" case ...) If you have the other solution I am listening

FN_RESTRICT :

```
/****************************************************************************/
-- purge de caractères indésirables
/****************************************************************************/
-- exemple : FN_RESTRICT('à Paris...?', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') => 'aris'
CREATE FUNCTION FN_RESTRICT (@IN VARCHAR (8000),
                             @CHARSOK VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS VARCHAR (8000)
AS 
BEGIN 
-- effets de bord
   IF @IN IS NULL
      RETURN NULL
   IF @CHARSOK IS NULL
      RETURN NULL
   IF LEN(@IN) = 0
      RETURN @IN
-- initialisation
   DECLARE @I INTEGER
   DECLARE @OUT VARCHAR(8000)
   SET @OUT = ''
-- lecture caractère par caractère
   SET @I =1
   WHILE @I <= LEN(@IN)
   BEGIN
      IF PATINDEX('%' + SUBSTRING(@IN, @I, 1)+ '%', @CHARSOK) > 0
         SET @OUT = @OUT + SUBSTRING(@IN, @I, 1)
      SET @I = @I + 1
   END
   RETURN @OUT
END
GO
```

Comment: You need another approach.  Even if you succeed in your cast, the resulting field will have a mixture of numbers and text which is not allowed.

Comment: More specifically, a single `CASE` expression has to have a single *type* of result. Which here would be `int` and so those strings in the `ELSE` clause are going to be converted anyway.

Comment: By your first cast, you tell the Server that the result will always be integer. As soon as you reach the first "complex" value, the conversion fails since it is varchar and not int. Cast the result of your FN_RESTRICT to varchar and you should be fine

Comment: Ok thank you, I understand why is not possible, @Tyron78 I will try your solution

Comment: @Tyron78 I added the function in my post, do you know where can I cast ? Because I took the function on the web but I don't realy understand how it work

Comment: since your function already returns varchar, simply replace `CAST(dbo.FN_RESTRICT(OPE_libelle, '0123456789') AS INTEGER)`in your query with `dbo.FN_RESTRICT(OPE_libelle, '0123456789')`

Comment: Oh yes ok ! It work but it don't solved my problem because the ORDER BY don't work without the cast on Integer type. I don't know if my problem have realy a solution...

Comment: Please provide an example basing on your example above: which order do you expect? You might succed with some WindowFunction, but let me see the expected result first.

Comment: @Tyron78 If we take my database extract above I would like the select OPE_libelle like that and in this order : 05,10,100,5030,5040,5050,5060, (and the rest at the end and not in order ) OP 10 à 20, OP 10 et OP 20, OP 10 7107, OP 10 7F094....

Comment: @Hilai see my answer for one possible approach. You can comment the second and third column in my query - I just left them in the output to better visualize the sorting of the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the following. However, I used a simple substring - you will have to put yoour function call there instead:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(
  OPE_libelle VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('OF 5030'), ('OF 5040'), ('OP 05'), ('OP 10'), ('OP 10 7107'), ('OP 10 et 20');

SELECT  t.OPE_libelle
       ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3)) = 1 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3) AS INT) ELSE NULL END AS OPE_libelle_Num
       ,CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3)) = 1 THEN CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1000)) ELSE t.OPE_libelle END AS OPE_libelle_Char
  FROM @t AS t
  ORDER BY ISNULL(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3)) = 1 THEN CAST(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3) AS INT) ELSE NULL END, 999999999)
          ,ISNULL(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3)) = 1 THEN CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1000)) ELSE t.OPE_libelle END, '_')
```

The idea is to convert to int whatever is possible in a new column in your query, then order by this column and afterwards by the alphanumeric value. Try replacing `SUBSTRING(t.OPE_libelle, 4, LEN(t.OPE_libelle)-3)`with your function call.

Result:

```
OPE_libelle OPE_libelle_Num OPE_libelle_Char
OP 05       5               NULL
OP 10       10              NULL
OF 5030     5030            NULL
OF 5040     5040            NULL
OP 10 7107  NULL            OP 10 7107
OP 10 et 20 NULL            OP 10 et 20
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was trying to do, thank you so much for this solution !